# Joda wrong offset when using ZoneInfoProvider

Tags: java, jodatime

Using Joda 2.1 in Java:
I have downloaded the latest timezone definitions 2013g, used ZoneInfoCompiler and have compiled those and moved them to my project's classpath.

I then call DateTimeZone.setProvider(new ZoneInfoProvider( "my-path-to-new-compiled-definitions" ) )

then when I try to instantiate new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jerusalem")) I get the time 1 hour backwards wrong.

It's as if compiling the new timezone definitions for joda and providing them has done nothing.  However to test that it is actually using my new location, I tried executing DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Khandyga") which did not exist in 2.1 and now retrieves and instantiates properly.

Ideas?

Comment: Could you please expand on the part that failed?  What code produced the failure, what value did you expect, and what did you get?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Asia/Jerusalem` is on DST until Oct 27.  That should be reflected in 2013g.  See also [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=110).

Comment: Also, probably unrelated to this issue, but you may want to updated to  the latest version 2.3 if possible.  See the release notes for [2.2](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto220.html) and for [2.3](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/upgradeto230.html) for details.

Comment: I expected to see the same time as i would on http://time.is/Tel_Aviv when running new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jerusalem"))... instead I got the time an hour backwards.

Comment: does ZoneInfoCompiler prefer the stuff that's baked into the JAR if it exists and only adds new tz definitions that do not exist inside the JAR?

Comment: No, if you compile new zones, it replaces the old data in entirety.  Is there any chance your computer's clock is not set correctly?  What OS are you running on?  If Windows, make sure you have applied [this update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2863058).